# Answer button help in java calculator

Tags: java, calculator

Following is my code i am trying to deal with, I have made every button work in the calculator but having no idea for = button code. Please help.

Case "+" is showing "result" in the textfield and other cases are giving me exceptions.

```
package calculator;

public class Calculator_JFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

double firstnum;
double secondnum;
double result;
String operation;


public Calculator_JFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    txtDisplay = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton8 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton9 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton10 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton11 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton12 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton13 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton14 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton15 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton16 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton17 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton18 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    txtDisplay.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    txtDisplay.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.RIGHT);

    jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton1.setText("1");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton2.setText("2");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton3.setText("3");
    jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton4.setText("+");
    jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton5.setText("4");
    jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton6.setText("5");
    jButton6.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton6ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton7.setText("6");
    jButton7.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton7ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton8.setText("-");
    jButton8.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton8ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton9.setText("7");
    jButton9.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton9ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton10.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton10.setText("8");
    jButton10.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton10ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton11.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton11.setText("9");
    jButton11.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton11ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton12.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton12.setText("*");
    jButton12.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton12ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton13.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton13.setText("0");
    jButton13.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton13ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton14.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    jButton14.setText("00");
    jButton14.setMargin(new java.awt.Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
    jButton14.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton14ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton15.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton15.setText(".");
    jButton15.setToolTipText("");
    jButton15.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton15ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton16.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton16.setText("/");
    jButton16.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton16ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton17.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton17.setText("C");
    jButton17.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton17ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton18.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton18.setText("=");
    jButton18.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton18ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

 javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new                 javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(txtDisplay)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton11, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton12, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton13, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton14, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton15)
                    .addGap(3, 3, 3)
                    .addComponent(jButton16, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton4)
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton17, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton18, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(txtDisplay, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 41, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton11,    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton12, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton13, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton14, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton15, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton16, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton17, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton18, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String input;
    input=txtDisplay.getText()+jButton1.getText();
    txtDisplay.setText(input);
}                                        

private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   firstnum=Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText());
   txtDisplay.setText("");
   operation="+";
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String input;
    input=txtDisplay.getText()+jButton2.getText();
    txtDisplay.setText(input);
}                                        

private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String input;
    input=txtDisplay.getText()+jButton5.getText();
    txtDisplay.setText(input);
}                                        

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String input;
    input=txtDisplay.getText()+jButton3.getText();
    txtDisplay.setText(input);
}                                        

private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String input;
    input=txtDisplay.getText()+jButton6.getText();
    txtDisplay.setText(input);
}                                        

private void jButton9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String input;
    input=txtDisplay.getText()+jButton9.getText();
    txtDisplay.setText(input);
}                                        

private void jButton10ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
   String input;
    input=txtDisplay.getText()+jButton10.getText();
    txtDisplay.setText(input);
}                                         

private void jButton11ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    String input;
    input=txtDisplay.getText()+jButton11.getText();
    txtDisplay.setText(input);
}                                         

private void jButton13ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    String input;
    input=txtDisplay.getText()+jButton13.getText();
    txtDisplay.setText(input);
}                                         

private void jButton14ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    String input;
    input=txtDisplay.getText()+jButton14.getText();
    txtDisplay.setText(input);
}                                         

private void jButton17ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    txtDisplay.setText("");
}                                         

private void jButton18ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    String ans;
    switch(operation){
        case "+":
           result=firstnum+secondnum;
           ans=String.valueOf(result);
           txtDisplay.setText(ans);
           break;

        case "-":
           result=firstnum-secondnum;
           ans=String.format("%.0f", result);
           txtDisplay.setText(ans);
           break;

        case "*":
           result=firstnum*secondnum;
           ans=String.format("%.0f", result);
           txtDisplay.setText(ans);
           break;

        case "/":
           result=firstnum/secondnum;
           ans=String.format("%.0f", result);
           txtDisplay.setText(ans);
           break;    


    }
}                                         

private void jButton15ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    String input;
    input=txtDisplay.getText()+jButton15.getText();
    txtDisplay.setText(input);
}                                         

private void jButton7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String input;
    input=txtDisplay.getText()+jButton7.getText();
    txtDisplay.setText(input);
}                                        

private void jButton8ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   firstnum=Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText());
   txtDisplay.setText("");
   operation="-";
}                                        

private void jButton12ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
   firstnum=Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText());
   txtDisplay.setText("");
   operation="*";
}                                         

private void jButton16ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
   firstnum=Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText());
   txtDisplay.setText("");
   operation="/";
}                                         

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info :  javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {                         java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Calculator_JFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
              java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Calculator_JFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
          java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Calculator_JFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
             java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Calculator_JFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Calculator_JFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton10;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton11;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton12;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton13;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton14;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton15;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton16;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton17;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton18;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton7;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton8;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton9;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtDisplay;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I need code for "="button bro. the above code i wrote for = button but its not working.

Comment: i guess error in `ans=String.format("%.of", result);` line. try `ans=String.valueOf(result);`

Comment: It seems that code for '=' is not present in your example.

Comment: ans=String.valueOf(result); is giving me the firstnumbr as answer. . . Riad... :-(

Comment: Try and print first and second number? your access specifier say "of" instead of 0(zero)f

Comment: Just tell me what is the exact error and at which line is it. 100% can get it fix.

Comment: with access specifier it gives me firstnumbr answr, mean it does no calculation just prints the first value i enter and ignores second value.

Comment: You apparently have designed a reverse Polish calculator.  (Seriously!)  Such calculators do not have `=` keys.

Comment: I have posted the whole code up there. Please recheck it and tell me what to do.

Comment: Look up "reverse Polish notation".

Answer (score 0):

it seems when typing the operation sign, you have already the two operands in the input;
and because you are doing basic operations (binary operations (that accepts only two arguments)), then your work is OK, and you don't need "=" operation, because operations are of the form:

```
op(arg1,arg2)
```

but if you are wiling to evaluate variadic operations (those that accept any number of variables), then you need the "=" sign in practice.

Finally, what about the exceptions?, you need to provide us with full stack trace, perhaps it's about formatting numbers which are Strings, check "%.of" perhaps it needs to be "%.0f".

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `String.valueOf` method otherwise will get a Run time error.

```
  result= firstnum-secondnum;
  ans=String.valueOf(result);
  System.out.println(ans);

break;
```

How this works: [See Live Demo](https://ideone.com/FamV1e)

Answer (score 0):

The *=* Operation type should be nothing more that the Identity operation, i.e. it returns the same value taken as argument:

```java
private void jButton18ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
  String ans;
  switch(operation){
    //...
    case "=":
      //Do nothing when the = sign is pressed as the result would remain the same
      txtDisplay.setText((result != 0) ? 
          Double.toString(result) : 
          Integer.toString(0));
      break;  
  }
}
```

### EDIT as per the main Question has been edited

You cannot absolutely use the `switch` statement on `String` literals. It can be only used on bytes, chars or Enum types.

As you are designing an Operation based calculator, I strongly recommend using an `Enum` type labeled `Operation` defining an abstract method for calculation method matter with constant specific implementations:

```java
public enum Operation
{
  ADD
      {
        @Override
        double apply(double argOne, double argTwo)
        {
          return argOne + argTwo;
        }
      },
  SUBSTRUCT
      {
        @Override
        double apply(double argOne, double argTwo)
        {
          return argOne - argTwo;
        }
      },
  DEVIDE
      {
        @Override
        double apply(double argOne, double argTwo)
        {
          return argOne / argTwo;
        }
      },
  MULTIPLY
      {
        @Override
        double apply(double argOne, double argTwo)
        {
          return argOne * argTwo;
        }
      };

  abstract double apply(double argOne, double argTwo);
}
```

Note that the above Enum type will let you gain in both flexibility in terms you can add as much operations as you want without hurting other software components, and you can use it as a `switch` label:

```java
public class Calculator_JFrame extends java.swing.JFrame
{
  //...
  private void jButton18ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
  {
    // Below instruction lets you second operator be updated with the second argument of the calculation, I presume that was the main issue why your calculation result shows as the firstnum (Because secondnum was never assigned)
    secondnum = Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText());
    switch (operation)
    {
      case ADD:
        result = operation.apply(firstnum, secondnum);
        txtDisplay.setText(Double.toString(result));
        break;

      case SUBSTRUCT:
        result = operation.apply(firstnum, secondnum);
        txtDisplay.setText(Double.toString(result));
        break;

      case MULTIPLY:
        result = operation.apply(firstnum, secondnum);
        txtDisplay.setText(Double.toString(result));
        break;

      case DEVIDE:
        result = operation.apply(firstnum, secondnum);
        txtDisplay.setText(Double.toString(result));
        break;
    }
  }
  //...
}
```

***Note:*** [Here](https://github.com/tmarwen/stackoverflow-showcase/tree/master/jframe-calculator) you can find a full featured working sample of your calculator.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you created a lot of buttons. Actually you can simply create an **array of buttons** and set the text of the button according to the array index.

When user presses the button, just use the **getText()** method to get the buttons' value.

The same applies for the mathematical operators **(+,-,*,/)**.

Creating **10 buttons** with **3 lines** of codes.

```
JButton[] button = new JButton[10];
for(int x=0; x<10; x++)
    button = new JButton(Integer.toString(x));  //create buttons 0-9
```

**At the actionListener:**

```
int valuePressed = Integer.parseInt(button.getText());
```

With these, your entire program will work elegantly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help. I finally made it working. Yahoooo. thanks for the suggestions.

```
package calculator;

public class Calculator_JFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

  float firstnum;
 float secondnum;
 float result;
 String operation;


public Calculator_JFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    txtDisplay = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton8 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton9 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton10 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton11 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton12 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton13 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton14 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton15 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton16 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton17 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton18 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);

    txtDisplay.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    txtDisplay.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.RIGHT);

    jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton1.setText("1");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton2.setText("2");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton3.setText("3");
    jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton4.setText("+");
    jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton5.setText("4");
    jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton6.setText("5");
    jButton6.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton6ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton7.setText("6");
    jButton7.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton7ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton8.setText("-");
    jButton8.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton8ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton9.setText("7");
    jButton9.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton9ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton10.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton10.setText("8");
    jButton10.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton10ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton11.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton11.setText("9");
    jButton11.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton11ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton12.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton12.setText("*");
    jButton12.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton12ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton13.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton13.setText("0");
    jButton13.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton13ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton14.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    jButton14.setText("00");
    jButton14.setMargin(new java.awt.Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
    jButton14.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton14ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton15.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton15.setText(".");
    jButton15.setToolTipText("");
    jButton15.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton15ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton16.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton16.setText("/");
    jButton16.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton16ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton17.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton17.setText("C");
    jButton17.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton17ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton18.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton18.setText("=");
    jButton18.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton18ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(txtDisplay)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton11, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton12, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton13, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton14, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton15)
                    .addGap(3, 3, 3)
                    .addComponent(jButton16, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton4)
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton17, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton18, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(txtDisplay, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 41, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton11, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton12, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton13, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton14, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton15, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton16, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton17, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton18, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String input;
    input=txtDisplay.getText()+jButton1.getText();
    txtDisplay.setText(input);
}                                        

private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
  try{        
   firstnum=Float.parseFloat(txtDisplay.getText());
   txtDisplay.setText("");
   operation="+";
  }
  catch (Exception e){
    txtDisplay.setText("Invalid Number");
  }
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String input;
    input=txtDisplay.getText()+jButton2.getText();
    txtDisplay.setText(input);
}                                        

private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String input;
    input=txtDisplay.getText()+jButton5.getText();
    txtDisplay.setText(input);
}                                        

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String input;
    input=txtDisplay.getText()+jButton3.getText();
    txtDisplay.setText(input);
}                                        

private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String input;
    input=txtDisplay.getText()+jButton6.getText();
    txtDisplay.setText(input);
}                                        

private void jButton9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String input;
    input=txtDisplay.getText()+jButton9.getText();
    txtDisplay.setText(input);
}                                        

private void jButton10ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
   String input;
    input=txtDisplay.getText()+jButton10.getText();
    txtDisplay.setText(input);
}                                         

private void jButton11ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    String input;
    input=txtDisplay.getText()+jButton11.getText();
    txtDisplay.setText(input);
}                                         

private void jButton13ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    String input;
    input=txtDisplay.getText()+jButton13.getText();
    txtDisplay.setText(input);
}                                         

private void jButton14ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    String input;
    input=txtDisplay.getText()+jButton14.getText();
    txtDisplay.setText(input);
}                                         

private void jButton17ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    txtDisplay.setText("");
}                                         

private void jButton18ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    secondnum=Float.parseFloat(txtDisplay.getText());       
    String ans;
     try{

    if(operation=="+"){
           result=firstnum+secondnum;
           ans=String.valueOf(result);
           txtDisplay.setText(ans);
    }else if(operation=="-"){

          result=firstnum-secondnum;
           ans=String.valueOf(result);
           txtDisplay.setText(ans);

    }else if (operation.equals("*")){
           result=firstnum*secondnum;
           ans=String.valueOf(result);
           txtDisplay.setText(ans);
    }else if(operation.equals("/")){
          result=firstnum/secondnum;
           ans=String.valueOf(result);
           txtDisplay.setText(ans);
    }
     }
     catch(Exception e){
      txtDisplay.setText("Enter Valid Number");
     }
}                                         

private void jButton15ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    String input;
    input=txtDisplay.getText()+jButton15.getText();
    txtDisplay.setText(input);
}                                         

private void jButton7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String input;
    input=txtDisplay.getText()+jButton7.getText();
    txtDisplay.setText(input);
}                                        

private void jButton8ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
  try{        
   firstnum=Float.parseFloat(txtDisplay.getText());
   txtDisplay.setText("");
   operation="-";
  }
  catch (Exception e){
    txtDisplay.setText("Invalid Number");
  }
}                                        

private void jButton12ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
  try{        
   firstnum=Float.parseFloat(txtDisplay.getText());
   txtDisplay.setText("");
   operation="*";
  }
  catch (Exception e){
    txtDisplay.setText("Invalid Number");
  }
}                                         

private void jButton16ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
  try{        
   firstnum=Float.parseFloat(txtDisplay.getText());
   txtDisplay.setText("");
   operation="/";
  }
  catch (Exception e){
    txtDisplay.setText("Invalid Number");
  }
}                                         

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Calculator_JFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Calculator_JFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Calculator_JFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Calculator_JFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Calculator_JFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton10;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton11;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton12;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton13;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton14;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton15;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton16;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton17;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton18;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton7;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton8;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton9;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtDisplay;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`Ans=eval (screenvalue);`

`Screenvalue` is a name where you see numbers once you click a button.
Basically, `screenvalue` is displayed number in your calculator screen.